# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: when SSL mutual authentication

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, keystore, truststore

I am trying to connect to a server(tomcat) that have two nodes(node1 & node2). Both server are HTTPS enabled with clientAuth="true"(Mutual authentication is enabled).

From a java client(Another web application deployed in another server) i am trying to connect to these servers.
In the java client i am setting the keystore & truststore path. Everything is working fine. But once a while we are getting the following exception in the client java program.

But once we restart the both server and client, the application again start working without any issue

```
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Any suggestion/help appreciated?

Comment: Are you using a self-signed CA cert? Are all the client certs issued by the same CA? When this happens do all subsequent SSL handshakes fail, or does this happen for only particular clients while others continue to work? If it's only certain clients, perhaps those clients actually have invalid certs (e.g., those client certs might have been signed by an older CA cert that is no longer trusted).

Comment: Which http client are you using?  I use Apache HttpClient and find that intermittent connection issues seem to look like HTTPS connection validation issues.